# Running javaCV on NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, javacv

Simple (and maybe stupid) question: Do I need to install openCV to use javaCV? I've already downloaded and imported javaCV libriaries to my Netbeans on MacOS. After running project i got multiple errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need OpenCV. OpenCV is in C/C++, the Java library is wrappers around it.